# I am trying to connect Lottery Contract to React Application using Metamask, But when I call manager() method on the contract I get an empty array

Tags: reactjs, blockchain, solidity, web3js

Account array is being logged perfectly fine and Metamask is running correctly, Ethereum is being used properly but every time I call manager() I just receive an empty array,

I am following a Udemy course of Stephen Grider

```
 // SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.5.0 <0.9.0;

contract Lottery {
    address public manager;
    address payable[] public players;

    constructor(){
       manager = msg.sender;
    }

    function enter() public payable{
        require(msg.value > 0.01 ether);
        players.push(payable(msg.sender));
    }

    function random() private view returns (uint){
        return uint256(
                keccak256(
                    abi.encodePacked(block.difficulty, block.number, players)
                )
            );
    }

    function pickWinner() public restricted {
        uint index = random() % players.length;
        address contractAddress = address(this);
        players[index].transfer(contractAddress.balance);
        players = new address payable[](0);
    }

    modifier restricted() {
        require(msg.sender == manager);
        _;
    }

    function getPlayers() public view returns(address payable[] memory){
        return players;
    }
 }
```

Frontend React Web3 initiation

```
import Web3 from "web3";

const web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);

export default web3;
```

Frontend React Contract Creation

```
import web3 from "./web3";

const contractAddress = "0x0C04a9a1587524dA1F2c65561Ca157f582242FC8";

const abi = [
  {
    inputs: [],
    stateMutability: "nonpayable",
    type: "constructor",
    constant: undefined,
    payable: undefined,
    signature: "constructor",
  },
  {
    inputs: [],
    name: "enter",
    outputs: [],
    stateMutability: "payable",
    type: "function",
    constant: undefined,
    payable: true,
    signature: "0xe97dcb62",
  },
  {
    inputs: [],
    name: "getPlayers",
    outputs: [[Object]],
    stateMutability: "view",
    type: "function",
    constant: true,
    payable: undefined,
    signature: "0x8b5b9ccc",
  },
  {
    inputs: [],
    name: "manager",
    outputs: [[Object]],
    stateMutability: "view",
    type: "function",
    constant: true,
    payable: undefined,
    signature: "0x481c6a75",
  },
  {
    inputs: [],
    name: "pickWinner",
    outputs: [],
    stateMutability: "nonpayable",
    type: "function",
    constant: undefined,
    payable: undefined,
    signature: "0x5d495aea",
  },
  {
    inputs: [[Object]],
    name: "players",
    outputs: [[Object]],
    stateMutability: "view",
    type: "function",
    constant: true,
    payable: undefined,
    signature: "0xf71d96cb",
  },
];

const lottery = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, contractAddress);

export default lottery;
```

Calling Contract Methods in App.js:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import web3 from "./web3";
import lottery from "./lottery";
const { ethereum } = window;

function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    //Calling Manager
    async function getManager() {
      const account = await ethereum.request({ method: "eth_requestAccounts" });
      console.log(account);

      const manager = await lottery.methods.manager().call({
        from: account[0],
      });
      console.log(manager);
    }

    getManager();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Lottery Contract</h2>
      <p>This Contract is managed by</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

I run your code and got this issue:

```
constructor(){
       manager = msg.sender;
    }
```

`msg.sender` should be payable. as far as I know, you do not need to explicitly declare that it is payable but since in `enter` function you have this line:

```
players.push(payable(msg.sender));
```

In typed strict languages, types should match. I run your solidity code and got this error:

[image]

if you change constructor to this :

```
 constructor (){
        manager = payable(msg.sender);
    }
```

Now it works

Comment: But manager is not address payable, its just address

Comment: And when I run the contract in remix, it works perfectly fine

Comment: different compilers might cause issue

Answer (score 0):

I am new to solidity and react so I am not 100% sure. But it seems `manager` is a variable of type address not an array. And since you are just calling it in react, would it not be:

```
const manager = await lottery.methods.manager().call();
```

Since you are only calling/getting the managers address, I do not think there is a need to set/send any values.

Comment: I tried that too, Still empty array

Comment: My second guess would be that it is inside `useEffect`. I believe maybe it has something to do with `async`. Maybe it would be better to use `setState` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Copy the abi from remix, not from the console.

Answer (score 0):

Think we were doing the same tutorial, I solved it just now, it was the `[ [Object] ]` part

I changed all code looking like this:

```
{
    inputs: [],
    name: "getPlayers",
    outputs: [[Object]],
    stateMutability: "view",
    type: "function",
    constant: true,
    payable: undefined,
    signature: "0x8b5b9ccc",
},
```

To code that looks like this:

```
{
        inputs: [],
        name: 'getPlayers',
        outputs: [ { internalType: 'address[]', name: '', type: 'address[]'} ],
        stateMutability: 'view',
        type: 'function',
        constant: true,
        payable: undefined,
        signature: '0x8b5b9ccc'
},
```

The reason was the console.log in the terminal from the abi when deploying the contract, I was trying solutions and instead of doing the console log to the ABI array, I did it with a forEach to inspect every object in the array, copy pasting manually all of the values solved the issue

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).